# SQL Server : join CALENDAR table and DATA table

Tags: sql-server

Can someone tell me why I can't get these tables to join? The first table is a dynamic `Calendar` table with just the date, and the second table is a data table with Date/Time, Behavior Name (String), Account# (int). I need to join these tables so that all the dates appear even if there isn't a behavior that day for that Account#.

I'm currently getting data that looks like this:

```
ACCT#     Date      Behavior 1        Behavior 2
-------------------------------------------------
123456   2/3/2018      1               3
123456   2/5/2018      1               2
123456   2/10/2018     1               0
123456   2/11/2018     1               0
```

I want / need for it to be:

```
ACCT#       Date      Behavior 1        Behavior 2
----------------------------------------------------
123456      2/1/2018      0               0
123456      2/2/2018      0               0
123456      2/3/2018      1               3
123456      2/4/2018      0               3
123456      2/5/2018      1               0
123456      2/6/2018      0               0
123456      2/7/2018      0               0
123456      2/8/2018      0               0
123456      2/9/2018      0               1
123456      2/10/2018     1               0
123456      2/11/2018     1               0
```

This is the query that I'm using

```
DECLARE @Start DATE, @End DATE, @Account# INT, @behavior varchar(50)
SET @Start = '2/1/2019';
SET @End = '3/20/2019';
SET @FSH = '123456';
SET @Behavior = 'Attack';

;WITH MonthDates AS 
(
    SELECT
        DATEADD(DAY, n1.number * 10 + n0.number, @Start) AS date
    FROM
        (SELECT 1 AS number UNION 
         SELECT 2 UNION 
         SELECT 3 UNION 
         SELECT 4 UNION 
         SELECT 5 UNION 
         SELECT 6 UNION 
         SELECT 7 UNION 
         SELECT 8 UNION 
         SELECT 9 UNION 
         SELECT 0) AS n0
    CROSS JOIN
        (SELECT 1 AS number UNION 
         SELECT 2 UNION 
         SELECT 3 UNION 
         SELECT 4 UNION 
         SELECT 5 UNION 
         SELECT 6 UNION 
         SELECT 7 UNION 
         SELECT 8 UNION 
         SELECT 9 UNION 
         SELECT 0) AS n1
    WHERE
        DATEADD(DAY, n1.number * 10 + n0.number, @Start) BETWEEN @Start AND @End
)
SELECT
    md.date,
    ACCT#,
    COUNT(CASE Behavior WHEN 'Behavior1' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Behavior1Alias,
    COUNT(CASE Behavior WHEN 'Behavior1' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Behavior2Alias
FROM
    vw_MaladaptiveDailySummary as vwMals
FULL JOIN 
    MonthDates AS md ON FORMAT(md.Date,'yyyy-MM-dd') = FORMAT(vwMals.Date,'yyyy-MM-dd')    
WHERE
    vwMals.Date >= @start AND vwMals.date <= @end 
    AND Account# = @FSH
GROUP BY
    md.date
ORDER BY
    md.Date
```

I have updated my query to the following:

```
declare @Start date, @End date, @FSH int, @behavior varchar(max)
Set @Start='2/1/2018';
Set @End ='12/20/2019';
Set @FSH ='123456';
set @Behavior = 'Attack';

SELECT

    MonthDates.Date
        ,count(case Behavior when 'Behavior1' then 1 else NULL end) as BehaviorsAlias1
    ,count(case Behavior when 'Behavior2' then 1 else null end) as BehaviorAlias2


FROM

    (   

        SELECT

            Date = DateAdd( Day, n1.number * 10 + n0.number, @Start )

        FROM

            (SELECT 1 AS number UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0) as n0

        CROSS JOIN

            (SELECT 1 AS number UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0) as n1

        WHERE   DateAdd( Day, n1.number * 10 + n0.number,@Start ) BETWEEN @Start AND @End


    ) AS MonthDates

LEFT JOIN vw_MaladaptiveDailySummary 

    ON vw_MaladaptiveDailySummary.DATE = MonthDates.Date

GROUP BY

    MonthDates.Date

ORDER BY

    MonthDates.Date
```

This does produce half of what I want;  the other half is to be able to filter the ACCT# /and/or Behavior.   The results I'm getting right now are the total of all ACCT#'s for that day.

```
Date      Behavior 1        Behavior 2
----------------------------------------------------
2/1/2018      5               0
2/2/2018      3               0
2/3/2018      1               3
2/4/2018      0               3
2/5/2018      1               0
2/6/2018      9               5
2/7/2018      6               0
2/8/2018      3               0
2/9/2018      0               8
2/10/2018     1               0
2/11/2018     1               6
```

Comment: Not sure what a lot of what your doing in there is (the unions on just numbers for one), but I thinkg change your join on the months table to LEFT JOIN.  Change your count to not use NULL but ELSE 0)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use. Your `DECLARE @behavior VARCHAR` declares a variable of **exactly 1 character** length - so your value is **NOT** `Attack` - but instead, it's just `A` ......

Comment: Thanks everybody for the comments  / suggestions.  I am still learning (SQL query)  so please excuse the bad coding.  some of the parameters in the query were put there just for the purpose of testing.  However I will try the suggestions.  This is actually a query for a SSRS report with a Chart.

Answer (score 0):

Despite using a FULL JOIN, you will only get rows that exist in `vw_MaladaptiveDailySummary` because you reference it in the WHERE clause:

```
vwMals.Date >= @start AND vwMals.date <= @end 
AND Account# = @FSH
```

Comment: I think I've tried a Full Join... saying that I think I've tried every join.. even the ones that don't exist.  j/k

Comment: The posted code uses a Full Join, so yes, you've tried it.   Do you not understand what I'm saying in my answer?

Comment: Sorry, Tab Alleman I didn't realize the posted code was a FULL JOIN.  The original code was a LEFT JOIN, and during all of my frustration I changed it to a FULL. I do understand the issue with the WHERE reference.  However I'm perplexed as how to filter the acct#  and still join the tables.